# Injecting authentication information

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have an app which connects to multiple sites with a different username/password pair for each. What I want to do is wire up dependencies so that I can say "whenever you want a FTPConnection, use this connection" and "this connection" depends on whatever the user wants.

So say I have a class like this (pseudo-Google Guice syntax):

```
public class FTPConnection
{
    FTPConnection(@Username String username, @Password String password)...
}
```

And a class that uses it

```
public class SomeFTPSiteProcessor
{
    SomeFTPSiteProcessor(@Inject FTPConnection)...
}
```

What I would like to do is have the "currently active" connection be created whenever I want an instance of SomeFTPSiteProcessor.

How would I do this? Would I use a scope? Would I use a provider? Help! Pseudo-code would be most appreciated.

I hope this makes some sense...

Edit: The user makes the choice of which FTP connection to use at runtime and so I need the authentication information to be provided dynamically. The language makes me think of a provider of sorts, but I can't quite wrap my head around how it would be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Robot Legs](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec) problem.

```
public class SomeFTPSiteProcessor
{
    SomeFTPSiteProcessor(@JeffsFtpServer FTPConnection)...
}

public class SomeOtherFTPSiteProcessor
{
    SomeFTPSiteProcessor(@FredsFtpServer FTPConnection)...
}

class FtpModule extends PrivateModule {
    String username;
    String password;
    Class<? extends Annotation> annotation;   

    void configure() {
         bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Username.class).with(username);
         bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Password.class).with(password);
         expose(FTPConnection.class).annotatedWith(annotation);
    }
}
Injector injector = Injector.createInjector(
    new FtpModule("fred", "password", FredsFtpServer.class), 
    new FtpModule("jeff", "password", JeffsFtpServer.class));
```

---

I think you would need a factory then. Likely with that factory having an instance of the injector.

```
class ThingieFactory() {
     @Inject Injector injector;

     SomeFTPSiteProcessor create(params... ) {
          return injector.createChild(new Module() { set params; } ).get(SomeFTPSiteProcessor.class);
     }
}
```

Comment: But this is a compile-time thing. I need this to be variable at runtime. Instead of slightly different instances of robot legs, think of number of legs (for example) being a value passed in by the user of a GUI. So the username and password are not known at compile time and are only known at some point later after the injector has created the root object. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you would need a factory then. Likely with that factory having an instance of the injector.

Comment: Dear god no... Anything but that. There has to be a way to do this. How do other applications handle "current user" injection?? I think it's very similar to that.

Comment: In a web context? Then session scoped objects. Do each of the items exist with in a logical scope?

Comment: It's not in a web context. It's a desktop app. I may need to think out the design a little more.

Comment: You can create scopes, but given the way you have described it I would be thinking about using an injected Injector or rethinking how it all sits together. Injecting the injector into a factory is not Evil. It is not a good thing either.